# passing different structure type in c for functions

Tags: pointers, structure

I have a  following code :

```
typedef struct PStruct{
int len;
char* data;
}PointerStruct;

typedef struct AStruct{
int len;
char data[256];
}ArrayStruct;

void checkFunc(PointerStruct* myData)
{
  if (0 == myData || 0 == myData->data){
  printf("error\n");
  }
}

int main()
{
   ArrayStruct my_data;
   my_data.len = 256;
   char data[] = "data is sent";
   my_data.data = &data;
   checkFunc((PointerStruct*)my_data);
   return 0;
 }
```

is there any wrong in passing structure which has array. where as the required is pointer.
please let me know.

Comment: A `char[]` is a type of `char*`. In one case the size is known at compile time and in the other it is not. You could technically just use `PointerStruct` since `len` is provided for both.

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple of points to be considered in your program.

```
char data[] = "data is sent";
```

This is a character array of 13 characters. Hence, `my_data.data = &data;` will give a compilation error as shown below

```
error: incompatible types when assigning to type 'char[256]' from  type 'char (*)[13]'
```

To copy your string, you could probably use strcpy as shown below

```
strcpy(my_data.data, data);
```

Next point is passing the pointer to the object. In this call, `checkFunc((PointerStruct*)my_data);`, you are passing the instance of the object to the function call, but are type-casting as a pointer. You would face compilation issues due to the mismatch of the datatypes as `error: cannot convert to a pointer type`

To overcome this error, you should pass a reference to your `my_data` object as `checkFunc((PointerStruct*) &my_data);`. Hence, your new `main` function would look like

```
int main()
{
    ArrayStruct my_data;
    my_data.len = 256;
    char data[] = "data is sent";
    //my_data.data = &data;
    strcpy(my_data.data, data); // Use of strcpy. You would require to include <string.h>
    checkFunc((PointerStruct*)(&my_data)); // Pass a reference and not by value
    return 0;
```

}

With these changes, your code should work fine.